# Recording sound card audio c# uwp

Tags: c#, audio, win-universal-app, audio-recording

i need to create a callrecorder for windows10(universal vindows project) Now i'm stuck. I tryed to make it with help of AudioGraphs and MediaCapture, to record input and output stream and submix them.But it seems that it is not possible to record from output in AG. Also i tryed CSCode/NAudio/WasApi libraries, but it seems thay not working with UWP, pls, give me some advice,  maybe it is possible to capture sound directly from audio card? I'm a beginner. Sorry for maybe dumb question.

Comment: To clarify: you want to capture not only input from the soundcard but also what's being output by the soundcard at that time?

Comment: Yea, using UWP,  if it's possible

Comment: Check official UWP C# Audio Creation Sample (Senario 2)